# Request for Permission box does not appear when user accepts my application

Tags: facebook

My facebook friend cannot successfully accept my application.

I created an application in facebook. When I invite a friend to my application the following happens:
1 - My friends receives an invite to my app.
2 - In my friend's page he is given a choice to either "accept" or hit "x" to decline.
3 - When my friend hits the "accept" button, the request disappears. the application is not added in his list of applications and he is not taken to the "Request for Permission" box.

When we checked his privacy settings, my application was not listed as an application he allowed permission to, even though he accept the application.

Why is this so?

The invite happens on my website with this call:
    FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',filters: ['app_non_users'],
        message: 'You should learn more about this awesome game.',
        data: 'tracking information for the user'});

I copied this from the FB site: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

Thanks.

Comment: Check if your application is put in Sandbox mode (in your App settings)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Sandbox mode for the application is disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using an intermediate page which sent a request permission call to facebook.